# Jquery: Add all spans of a certain class to an ordered list

Tags: jquery, list, reference, html

I am trying to make a list of footnotes at the bottom of my document based on on class of spans, like this:

```
<h1>Header</h1>

<p>The first sentenece<span class="refer">First source</span></p>

<p>A second paragraph<span class="refer">Another source</span></p>



<hr />

<h2>References</h2>

<div id="references">
<ol>

</ol>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var listitem =  $(".refer").text();
   $("ol").append("<li>" + listitem + "</li>");
 });

</script>
```

Eventually I also want to replace the spans with a superscript number referring to the footnote. Currently this script adds all of the references to the same footnote (the same list item.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your problem is that you were trying to take the text of an entire collection of elements (all `span.refer` elements) all at once, and put it into a `li`. What you want to do is take the text of each `span.refer` element (one at a time), put it into its own `li`, and then add it to the `ol`.

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var listItems = "";

     $(".refer").each(function() {
           var listitem =  $(this).text();
           listItems += "<li>" + listitem + "</li>";
     });

     $("ol").append(listItems);
 });
```

Comment: That worked like gangbusters, thanks! I'm still exploring this world called jQuery, trying to learn by doing.

Comment: Might be more efficient to build a string with the `each` loop and call `append` **after**, one time.

Comment: @Ian - Nice! I'm going to adopt and expand. Give me a moment

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Sounds good :) It would just use less DOM interaction, which is definitely preferred. Your answer is clearly right, I was just trying to expand on it

Comment: @Ian - Done! I built the string in the loop, then applied it to the DOM with a single call. The program just went from `n * O(n^2)` to `O(n^2)` (if I did that math right haha)! Thanks for the assist!!! :)

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Looks great! Yeah I think that math is right. No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way...

```
// select elements to create references from
$(".refer")
    // for each one of them, add a ` [i]` where `i` is the index
    .after(function(i){ return "<sup>"+(i+1)+"</sup>" })
    // then append each one to the `ol` (better done by ID when there are more elements on the page)
    .appendTo("ol")
    // then wrap each one in an `li` element
    .wrap("<li></li>")
```

I have no idea about performance, but I think this way reflects closely the intent, so is easy to read, and maintain.

The `.after` function, adds the index reference in place, using a generic index value to track the item number (as in, it does not get the index value from the items themselves).

The `.appendTo` function moves the elements from where they were, into the ordered list, and still returns all the items in the list, so is chainable to the `.wrap` function, which adds some arbitrary element around each of the originally selected items.

Comment: I expect this would work quite well performance wise, because you are only creating one jQuery object, and re-using it through chaining. It is usually best to avoid creating jQuery objects if possible, as they are expensive.

Comment: +1 Great solution, and very cool use of `.after`! Quick question about this, though: won't it be expensive to append each one to the `<ol>` separately, and then to wrap each on in an `<li>`? I see O(n^4) because of the `.after` loop, the `.appendTo()` (as it happens for each) and the `.wrap` loop (as it also happens for each). I know jQuery objects are expensive, but isn't doubling the number of loops going to be more expensive? I know that it could be less expensive with a very small list, but, aside from that, how would it match up?

Comment: I don't know which would perform better with different browsers and list sizes. Sounds like a job for http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 0):

or a little bit better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".refer").each(function(index, el) {
       var listitem =  $(this).text();
       $("ol").append("<li>" + listitem + "</li>");

       $(this).replaceWith($('<sup>' + (index+1) + '</sup>'));
     });
});
```

Comment: perhaps `$(this).html()` would be better, in case there are any significant HTML elements in the reference, so they don't get stripped out. Also, perhaps an explanation of why this is better might be useful, I don't think it is completely obvious what the improvement is.